# Truncate a string by words, add a count of not listed items at the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Many of the ways of truncating a string have been covered but I couldn't find anywhere that my case was covered.

Here is the case:

First user's language array:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "label": "English", },
    {"id": 2, "label": "French", },
]
```

Second user's language array:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "label": "English", },
    {"id": 2, "label": "French", },
    {"id": 3, "label": "German", },
    {"id": 4, "label": "Turkish", }
]
```

Third user's language array:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "label": "Farsi", },
    {"id": 2, "label": "Dutch", },
    {"id": 3, "label": "German", },
    {"id": 4, "label": "Turkish", }
    {"id": 5, "label": "English", }
]
```

I concatenate the languages with commas and if the total length is bigger than `15`, I want to break by words and add a count of not listed languages at the end.

Please note, I don't want to include the last language if the limit is exceeded as seen in the third example below.

I want to show this in my UI like this:

First user:

`English, French`

Second user:

`English, French, +2`

Third user:

`Farsi, Dutch, +3`

Here is how I concatenate:

```
const languageLabels = props?.languages?
      .map(({label}) => label)
      .join(", ")
      .toString()
```

This gives a result for the second example like the following:

`English, French, German, Turkish`

Edit:
I want to add an edge case.

Fourth user's language array:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "label": "Arabic (Egyptian Spoken)", },
]
```

In that case, I want to display:
`Arabic (Egyp...`

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to display a list of languages per user as long as the first two languages combined do not exceed 15 chars. Am I right?

Comment: Partially yes. I want to display a list of the languages per user. If the list exceeds 15 chars, I want to break the list and add the count of the languages that are not displayed. The first language would be longer than 15 chars. In that case, I want to display only the first language and slice it. I have added that edge case. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: So the display of the count is not included in the 15 character limit?

Comment: Yes. Your solution(accepted answer) is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over the labels building the string, and stopping when the next extension of the string would overflow the limit.

Then deal with the case where the string would still be too long (the boundary case), and add the counter (if any is needed):

```js
function limitedString(arr, maxlen) {
  let s = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let next = s + (i ? ", " : "") + arr[i].label;
    if (next.length > maxlen) {
      if (!i) {
        s = next.slice(0, maxlen - 3) + "...";
        i++;
      }
      return arr.length - i ? s + ", +" + (arr.length - i) : s;
    }
    s = next;
  }
  return s;
}

// The examples you have given:
const tests = [
  [{
      "id": 1,
      "label": "English",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "label": "French",
    },
  ],
  [{
      "id": 1,
      "label": "English",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "label": "French",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "label": "German",
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "label": "Turkish",
    }
  ],
  [{
      "id": 1,
      "label": "Farsi",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "label": "Dutch",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "label": "German",
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "label": "Turkish",
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "label": "English",
    }
  ],
  [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "Arabic (Egyptian Spoken)",
  }, ]
];

for (const test of tests) {
  console.log(limitedString(test, 15));
}
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question clearly. If not, please let me know.

So assuming we have an array languages as follows:

```
const languages = [
    {"id": 1, "label": "English", },
    {'id': 2 , 'label': 'Arabic (Egyptian Spoken)'},
    {"id": 2, "label": "French", },
    {"id": 3, "label": "German", },
    {"id": 4, "label": "Turkish", }
    ]
```

We would like to display the first two languages. If one of them has a length exceeding 15 then we truncate it to the first 12 chars of. And we add a +n after them where n is the number of languages NOT displayed. correct?

In that case, the function below deals with truncating languages that exceed 15 in length:

```
function truncateLongLanguage(language) {
    let truncatedLang = ''
    truncatedLang = language.length > 15 ? language.slice(0,12).concat('..') : language
    
    return truncatedLang
}
```

We then map the languages array: (this assumes you have at least two objects in the array)

```
let textToDisplay = languages .map(l => l.label).slice(0,2).map(l => truncateLongLanguage(l)).join(', ') + ', +' + (languages .map(l => l.label).length - 2)
```

In case you are not sure that you will always have 2 objects in the array, you can simply use if-else to check

```
someFunctionName (languages) {
   if (languages.length === 1) { 
       return truncateLongLanguage(languages[0].label)
   }

   return languages.map(l => l.label).slice(0,2).map(l => 
   truncateLongLanguage(l)).join(', ') + ', +' + (languages .map(l => 
   l.label).length - 2)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. You are adding a count of all the languages, not the not listed ones. Also, the language array would have only one language that is longer than 15 chars. Please see the edge case in the OP.

Comment: I think I understand your situation a bit better now (although not 100% tbh). Either way I updated my code to deal with your edge cases. I hope it can be more helpful now